The file is not checked out (unable to delete/release lock/discard checkout)
User uploaded .xlsm file and somehow it got corrupted or something happened. Even though this file not checked out to anyone, when you use GUI to check out the file then you receive error message The file is not checked out
I tried following methods but none works.

Deleting file from GUI and PowerShell is not working
$SPFile.UndoCheckOut using PowerShell is not working
$SPFile.ReleaseLock using PowerShell is not working
Versioning is enabled and unable to restore previous version

When trying to display some values it shows the following:
$SPFile.CheckoutStatus value is ShortTerm.
$SPFile.CheckOutType value is None
$SPFile.CheckOutBy value is the username of user who checked out the file (even though it is not)
I am site collection admin and have full access. What to do now?

Tried to delete it from GUI again after an hour and now I was able to do it. Looks like some kind of lock that was released by SharePoint after an hour or so?

Thank you so much for sharing. It helps a lot!
